# 7z, how to unzip without __MACOSX folder in terminal

Tags: terminal, 7zip

I try to unzip a file with using x to keep the folder structure inside. But it creates a __MACOSX folder which I do not wish to have

At my project directory, I tried

```
7z x -y ./app/resources/Docs.zip -o./app/resources/Docs -x "__MACOSX"
```

But I got an error:

```
Too short switch:
-x
```

Please advice how can I extract a zip file and keep its folder structure but without the __MACOSX folder?

Answer (score 0):

You must put -x in quotes:

```
7z x -y ./app/resources/Docs.zip "-o./app/resources/Docs" "-x__MACOSX"
```